# some url does't work to play online radio in android

Tags: android, streaming

I'm building an Android app that will stream several radio stations from my country, i used

some url, and they don't work for me.  here the code :

```
 private void startStreamingAudio() {
        try { 
            final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            if ( audioStreamer != null) {
                audioStreamer.interrupt();
            }
            audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this,textStreamed, playButton, streamButton,progressBar);

            audioStreamer.startStreaming("http://stream.mosaiquefm.net/mosaique64k?MSWMExt=.asf",5208, 216);
            streamButton.setEnabled(false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error starting to stream audio.", e);                  
        }
```

so whene i change an other url for exemple this URL :

> http://npr.ic.llnwd.net/stream/npr_live24  it works fine.

i just want to know, why the code works with some URL, and not with some other !
thank you helping me..

Comment: can you give some urls that work and some that dont?

Comment: those url works fine : 
http://npr.ic.llnwd.net/stream/npr_live24
http://broadcast.infomaniak.net:80/alouette-high.mp3
http://listen.radionomy.com/punchradiofm

those dones not works :
http://stream.mosaiquefm.net/?MSWMExt=.asf
and others !. i just can't realise why ! so please help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your `StreamingMediaPlayer` class is, but the [supported list of natively supported media formats for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) does not include ASF.

Comment: i just don't know, i have a doubt, that there is a type of url can be streamed and buffered on the volatile memory on the android device.

something like that.
someone could hlp please !!

Comment: I have no idea what you meant by that comment at all, but to restate my answer: Android doesn't magically natively support all formats. ASF is one of those formats that is not supported. You are trying to load an ASF stream. This means you're trying to load a stream that Android does not understand. It will not work.

Comment: so what you think about this uRL http://npr.ic.llnwd.net/stream/npr_live24 , can you tell me what format on this link !?

Comment: I would say it looks like a MPEG Audio layer 1/2/3 (mpga), Mono channel, bitrate 32 kb/s and sample rate 22050 Hz stream.

Comment: please help how to stream any radio station that i want !?